# ChildNodes of DOMDocument lost order

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a html string. I want to traverse it and extract some information. My code is as following:

```
$str = '<p>aaa</p><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"/><p>sss</p><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>';

function parseContent($str) {
    $contents = array();

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    if (!$dom->loadHTML($str)) {
        return $contents;
    }

    $stack = array($dom);
    while (count($stack) > 0) {
        $node = array_shift($stack);
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $node) {
            if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
                $stack[] = $node;
            } else {
                switch ($node->nodeType) {
                    case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                        if ('img' == $node->tagName) {
                            $contents[] = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue;
                        }
                        break;
                    case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                        $contents[] = $node->textContent;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

The problem is: When I dumped the return value of this function, it was something like this:

```
array(
    'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    'aaa',
    'sss',
)
```

Could someone point it out why the order was lost?

Comment: Because `<p>` has child node (a text node), so it's stacked one more time.

Comment: @Passerby Could you please make it an answer? I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from comment:

That's because each `<p>` also has child node (a text node), so they go into the first `if ($node->hasChildNodes())` statement and are stacked one more time.

To avoid this, one way is to add one more condition:

```
/* ... */
if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
    if ($node->childNodes->length==1 && $node->childNodes->item(0)->nodeType==XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        $contents[] = $node->childNodes->item(0)->textContent;
    } else {
        $stack[] = $node;
    }
} else {
/* ... */
```